# Java Datestring, how to create long Day of the Week format?

Tags: javascript, date-formatting

This is a script that counts a desired number of business days from the present time. It works very well. I would like it to render the result as a long word day of the week, as in **Monday July 06 2015**, for example. The current result is **Mon Jul 06 2015**

I am a hacking monkey, so a dumbed-down response would not be an insult!

```js
Number.prototype.mod = function(n) {
  return ((this % n) + n) % n;
}
Date.prototype.addBusDays = function(dd) {
  var wks = Math.floor(dd / 5);
  var dys = dd.mod(5);
  var dy = this.getDay();
  if (dy === 6 && dd > -1) {
    if (dys === 0) {
      dys -= 2;
      dy += 2;
    }
    dys++;
    dy -= 6;
  }
  if (dy === 0 && dd < 1) {
    if (dys === 0) {
      dys += 2;
      dy -= 2;
    }
    dys--;
    dy += 6;
  }
  if (dy + dys > 5) dys += 2;
  if (dy + dys < 1) dys -= 2;
  this.setDate(this.getDate() + wks * 7 + dys);
}

var today = new Date();
today.addBusDays(1);
document.getElementById('dtt').innerHTML = today.toDateString();
```

Usage: We use it in a full sentence:

```
Your package will arrive on or before <span id="dtt"></span>.
```

Comment: You can do it manually by getting each of the properties of the `Date` object (day of week, month, day, and year), but consider using a library like [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) to save some work.

Comment: Thank you for the thought but I have tried to understand moments.js and can't get it in my head.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create an array of month/day names like so:

```
var days = ["Sunday","Monday",...]; 
var months = ["January", "February", ...];
```

And then

```
function formatDate(date) {
    var day = date.getDate();
    if(day < 10) {
        day = "0" + day;
    }
    return days[date.getDay()] + " " + months[date.getMonth()] + " " + day + " " + date.getFullYear();
}

console.log(formatDate(new Date()));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/1xe39uut/2/

Comment: I know the right answer is in your response, but as a hack, I don't know where to place those suggestions in the script.

Comment: `document.getElementById('dtt').innerHTML = formatDate(today);` instead of using `today.toDateString();` http://jsfiddle.net/1xe39uut/3/

Comment: Oh goodness, Sebastian, I just saw the fiddle you created. Thank you. I will get working on that.

Comment: Sebastian, I now have the moment to work with what you wrote out for me. I thank you very much for sharing this with me. It is working perfectly and I am grateful for the kindness of your time. /PS